# Update existing records after adding new trigger on object

Tags: apex, trigger

I have written trigger on child object (Contact) for show count of child records on parent records(Account in lookup relationship).

Trigger is working fine, but it only if any of child record is update, it will populate a count, it is obvious because there are existing records on which trigger not executed so count is not populated.

How I can sync existing Account object so that count will be get populate? one way is to written down Batch Apex which is update one contact from each account so count get populate. is there any way to handle it?

Comment: Is it a one off update you need to do? You could just use the dateloader, export all the children's id then use it to update them. Also has the benefit of testing your trigger for bulk operations.

Comment: If it's one-off then write the code for the batch and execute it once through execute anonymous.